# How to import jquery to vendor.ts Angular 2 webpack

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to set up angular 2 app based on webpack.
I see that in vendor.ts we have that structure.

```
// Angular 2
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';

// RxJS
import 'rxjs';


// Other vendors for example jQuery, Lodash or Bootstrap
// You can import js, ts, css, sass, ...
```

I want to import jQuery (for example) but I don't know what. Because when I tried to do that but it's not working. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

```
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
```

So I don't have idea why rxjs imported OK but jquery not :)

Comment: Try `import $ from 'jquery'`

Comment: Hi Alexey. It is working, but I don't  uderstand why they import import '@angular/core';    in vendor.ts and then they do the same in inner modules/components.  Should I do the same with jQuery? **import jQuery** to the vendor.ts and after that do the same in inner modules?

Comment: I may be wrong (just starting with ng2 myself) but I think that by importing angular/core in vendor.ts you tell webpack to include that module into the resulting bundle, and later in your code you usually import some specific parts of the module like `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';` - that way you can use `NgModule` in your code.

Comment: Now I understand that  moment. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I helped you, so I changed my comment to answer, you can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I implemented it:

1. I have an alias in `resolve` section of my Webpack config file:

   `resolve: {
       ...
       alias: { 
           jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
       }
     }`

   this will allow you to write

   `import 'jquery';`

   instead of

   `import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';`

   in vendor.ts
2. Use Webpack `ProvidePlugin` to make `jQuery` and `$` global:

   `plugins: [
   ...
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     $: 'jquery',
     jQuery: 'jquery',
     "window.jQuery": 'jquery'
   }),
   ...
   ]`

I may be wrong (just starting with ng2 myself) but I think that by importing angular/core in vendor.ts you tell Webpack to include that module into the resulting bundle, and later in your code you usually import some specific parts of the module like `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';` - that way you can use `NgModule` in your code.